Why does my terminal on OSX (iTerm2) not need me to reset the echo flag?
I'm trying to get a handle on terminal flags (to build up a terminal based UI) and so I'm following this guide Entering Raw Mode but with Zig.
If I turn off echo with this snippet
const std = @import("std");
const c = @cImport({
    @cInclude("termios.h");
    @cInclude("unistd.h");
    @cInclude("stdlib.h");
});

const os = std.os;

pub fn disableEcho() !void {
    var raw = try os.tcgetattr(c.STDIN_FILENO);
    raw.lflag &= ~(@as(u32,c.ECHO));
    try os.tcsetattr(c.STDIN_FILENO, .FLUSH, raw);
}

pub fn main() !void {

    try disableEcho();

    var char: u8 = undefined;

    const stdin = std.io.getStdIn().reader();

    while (true) {
        char = try stdin.readByte();
        if (char == 'q') break;
        std.debug.print("c = {}\n\r", .{char});
    }

    std.debug.print("\n", .{});
}

I notice that echo is turned off only for the execution of my program. I notice that the guide says

Let’s be nice to the user and restore their terminal’s original attributes when our program exits

but my echo comes right back on. Is this expected behavior? Are some terminals different at restoring state?
Note I'm using iTerm2 on OSX. Edit: I'm also using ZSH.
When I accidentally turned off way more flags by accident my terminal still went back to normal after the program exited. I expected to be able to wreck my terminal and be forced to close and re-open it to be honest.

Looking at the bash source control, when using bash as your shell, libreadline turns on local echo in the function rl_prep_terminal, which is the default target of the rl_prep_term hook, which is called from rl_callback_newline before displaying the prompt. Which is to say, at least one common shell takes on some relevant responsibility itself. Still polite for your program to put things back on its own rather than relying on belt-and-suspenders elsewhere.

Good point! It's probably a zsh thing since Mac now comes with zsh by default. Yeah I agree I should probably just set it back to how it was in order to be nicely behaved.

One thing you could try doing to test if it's just the shell or if iTerm does have some logic is to run your program direct from a separate programming language -- call it from a tiny Python program or the like, then read a line of input when it returns.

Just launched it from bash instead of zsh. Turns out that the echo flag doesn't get reset for bash.

Note that I was looking at the source to a very modern version of bash, and Apple ships one that's well over a decade old (because they don't agree to the license newer releases are shipped under); so it's not surprising for behaviors to differ.
